# Wondering Why This Is Crashing Constantly?

Tags: ios, logging, crash-reports

Hi I just updated the Simpsons Tapped Out to version 4.0

Anywho every 5 minutes it crashes. Here's my crash log. Does anyone know what it means exactly or what's causing the crash. I'm asking because I'm curious if there's something I can do on my side to fix it as a user. Thanks!!!

```
    Incident Identifier: 26C0FFA9-AB7E-4201-B120-E33790FF28AE
CrashReporter Key:   cd183bfeae20b2f5138f389b9804f3261bbd0408
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         Tapped Out [3267]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/5905994C-633C-419E-9359-666310E55EFE/Tapped Out.app/Tapped Out
Identifier:      Tapped Out
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-12-07 14:10:33.420 -0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A525)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Tapped Out                      0x00524cfc 0x43000 + 5119228
1   Tapped Out                      0x005495fa 0x43000 + 5268986
2   Tapped Out                      0x0054a5ca 0x43000 + 5273034
3   Tapped Out                      0x00520cf4 0x43000 + 5102836
4   Tapped Out                      0x00533ab6 0x43000 + 5180086
5   Tapped Out                      0x0052ec22 0x43000 + 5159970
6   Tapped Out                      0x0052ec22 0x43000 + 5159970
7   Tapped Out                      0x0052ec22 0x43000 + 5159970
8   Tapped Out                      0x0013cc40 0x43000 + 1023040
9   Tapped Out                      0x000900cc 0x43000 + 315596
10  Tapped Out                      0x0008fe7c 0x43000 + 315004
11  Tapped Out                      0x0051c598 0x43000 + 5084568
12  Tapped Out                      0x0056afa4 0x43000 + 5406628
13  Tapped Out                      0x0056c534 0x43000 + 5412148
14  QuartzCore                      0x39a8677c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 156
15  QuartzCore                      0x39a866d4 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 60
16  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x32dcdfd4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 152
17  IOKit                           0x3255d5aa IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 190
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3a148888 __CFMachPortPerform + 116
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3a1533e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3a153386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3a15220a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3a0c5238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3a0c50c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24  GraphicsServices                0x3a221336 GSEventRunModal + 70
25  UIKit                           0x339e228c UIApplicationMain + 1116
26  Tapped Out                      0x002d1b04 0x43000 + 2681604
27  Tapped Out                      0x00045844 0x43000 + 10308

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed85d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32f6bd22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32f67374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed7e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed7fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3a1532b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3a15202c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0c5238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0c50c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x34f65a58 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x334630de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33462fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed7e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed7fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3a1532b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3a15202c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0c5238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0c50c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x32ac5098 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x32b48a3c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x334630de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33462fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ee8594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3a157474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x334630de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33462fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ee8d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33458ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x334587f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33458680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed7e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ed7fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   AudioToolbox                    0x3902c3a8 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 104
3   AudioToolbox                    0x3902e734 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 4
4   AudioToolbox                    0x38f6c442 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 294
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x334630de _pthread_start + 306
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33462fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
```

Comment: "I'm asking because I'm curious if there's something I can do on my side to fix it as a user." - send the report to the app developers.

Comment: Anyway, even considering my doubts about whether this is an appropriate question for SO, I don't see how anyone could reasonably answer this, seeing as the crash log doesn't have debug symbols for the code where the crash occurred. (Not like that would be nearly enough to provide a fix.)

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Like EA cares lol. They're the worst with crashes. And It is a programming question, because if someone knew what was wrong I would know where to begin (if I could at all). For now I've hacked the main file to take the falling snow off, and it's helped. Thanks for your time though. I guess only EA can do it then. That cleared it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash report is symbolicated. Nobody will be able to make sense of it without the dsym file that accompanies it (which only the developer will have).

Comment: This isn't an answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. I'm a developer and jailbreaker. I was wondering because I'd like to try to find a way to fix it, but I guess you're right it won't be useful.

Comment: It is an answer because my question was if by looking at a crash log, if a user could fix a crash for an app without having made the app or owning the xcode project. And he answered it, I mean everyone did.